# Potential Sales Loss Query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am building a dashboard to display potential Sales loss for a E-commerce company. potential sales loss is when a customer orders a product but we don't have that product in our inventory at that point of time. for this i used the variables product ID, amount, quantity bought, out_of_stock(product in the nearest inventory) which will be in hours (0-24), The time order_placed_time.
My logic was based on the aggregating quantity of the product based on product_id with where clause (out of stock hours was 0), once after that I'll compare the value with a clause where ( out of stock is not 0) and the average difference between the quantities for products based on each day will give us the the quantity that we lost. This value will be then multiplied with the amount/rate of product on that particular date to get the potential sales loss.

The query used

```
with CTE_1 as(select * from (select darkstore_product_id,
       out_of_stock,
       express_out_of_stock,
       manually_stock_out_time,
       log_date
from daily_product_stock_logs
where out_of_stock > 0 or express_out_of_stock > 0 or manually_stock_out_time is not null) b
where b.log_date > current_date - interval '60 days'),
CTE_2 as (select product_id,actual_price,description,Date from (select product_id,
       round(avg(amount/qty)) as actual_price,
       date(order_line_items.created_at::timestamp AT time zone INTERVAL '-05:30') as Date
from order_line_items
group by Date,order_line_items.product_id) b
left join product_details using(product_id)
where b.Date > current_date - interval '60 days')
select * from CTE_1 left join CTE_2 on CTE_1.darkstore_product_id = CTE_2.product_id;
```

Please let me know if my logic or query is wrong.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Are you using MySQL or PostgreSQL? I remove all other irrelevant tags. Please pay attention to their description next time